# Vue.js not correctly rendering dynamically loaded select tag options

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, vue.js

I'm trying to render a select tag with options loaded from a Vue object, but, as you can see by the way this is rendered, it looks like something's wrong:

[image]

Now this is the markup for the select tag:

```
<div class="form-group ui-model">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SenderWalletId, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedSenderWallet">
            <option v-if="!walletsLoaded" disabled>Loading wallets...</option>
            <option v-if="walletsLoaded" v-for="wallet in wallets" v-bind:value="wallet.id">{{ wallet.description }}</option>
        </select>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SenderWalletId, new { }, new { value = "selectedSenderWallet" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SenderWalletId)
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script for creating the Vue app, along with SignalR taking care of the wallets (setWallets is called by the hub after successfully loading the wallets from my repository):

```
<script>
    var walletLinkText = Vue.extend({
        props: ['wallet'],
        template: '<span>{{ linkText }}</span>',
        computed: {
            linkText: function () {
                return this.wallet.description + ' (' + this.wallet.currentAmountFormatted + ')';
            }
        }
    });

    var uiModel = new Vue({
        el: '.ui-model',
        data: {
            wallets: [],
            walletsLoaded: false
        },
        components: {
            'wallet-link-text': walletLinkText
        }
    });

    $(function() {
        var walletsHubProxy = $.connection.walletsHub;

        walletsHubProxy.client.updateWallet = function (...) {
            ...
        };

        walletsHubProxy.client.setWallets = function (currentWallets) {
            uiModel.wallets = currentWallets;
            uiModel.walletsLoaded = true;
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            walletsHubProxy.server.getWallets();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The thing is I'm sure wallets are loaded correctly as you can see in the menu:

[image: Wallets loading]

[image: Wallets loaded]

And this is the html markup for the above:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ui-model">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Wallets <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li v-if="!walletsLoaded"><a><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Loading...</a></li>
            <li v-if="walletsLoaded && !wallets.length"><a>No wallets.</a></li>
            <li v-if="walletsLoaded" v-for="wallet in wallets">
                <a v-bind:href="'@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Wallets/"))' + wallet.id">
                    <wallet-link-text :wallet="wallet"></wallet-link-text>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Add", "Wallets")"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Add new</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So where am I wrong? I feel like I'm stuck on something really simple.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. the last screenshot seems to show that everything is working fine. So when/how does the situation of the first screenshot happen? Generally, Vue apps look like this when there's an error and the template wasn't compiled by Vue. Look at your console.

Comment: The problem is in the first screenshot: options are not rendered at all. I posted other screenshots to support the fact that with the same Vue app the menu is correctly rendered as opposed with the select tag. And the console doesn't show anything (and yes, I'm using the development version).

Comment: Try using `v-else`instead of `v-if="walletsLoaded"` in the second option.

Comment: I already tried removing the conditional rendering, and even given the v-else a try, but the result is still the same. The problem is definitely not in the conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Vue can only be mounted within one context element: .ui-model refers to several elements in the DOM, therefore just the first is rendered correctly (the menu). If I create another Vue app the code works as expected:

```
<div class="form-group" id="wallets-app">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WalletId, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedWallet">
            <option v-if="!walletsLoaded" disabled>Loading wallets...</option>
            <option v-else v-for="wallet in wallets" v-bind:value="wallet.id">{{ wallet.description }}</option>
        </select>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.WalletId, new { }, new { value = "selectedWallet" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WalletId)
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#wallets-app',
        data: {
            wallets: [],
            walletsLoaded: false,
            selectedWallet: ''
        }
    });

    //SignalR code to sync hubs and ui
</script>
```

I wanted a single array of data to be shared between multiple elements, so that each element would've had its own html representation, its view. Instead I have to pass the array of wallets to each of the Vue apps I want to be reactive to updates.

Well, it seems unefficient to me, but I'm sure I'm missing something. Feel free to add any suggestions and/or corrections.

**EDIT:** the correct way to achieve the result I wanted was to simply put all the data into a *store* object, in order to share the same data across multiple components (such as menu items for each of the wallets).

```
<div class="form-group" id="select-wallet">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.WalletId, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedWallet">
            <option v-if="!sharedData.walletsLoaded" disabled>Loading wallets...</option>
            <option is="wallet-select-option" v-else v-for="wallet in sharedData.wallets" v-bind:wallet="wallet"></option>
        </select>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.WalletId, new { }, new { value = "selectedWallet" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WalletId)
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var store = {
        data: {
            wallets: [],
            walletsLoaded: false
        }
    };

    Vue.component('wallet-select-option', {
        props: ['wallet'],
        template: '<option v-bind:value="wallet.id">{{ wallet.description }}</option>'
    });

    var selectWallet = new Vue({
        el: '#select-wallet',
        data: {
            sharedData: store.data,
            selectedWallet: ''
        }
    });


    $(function () {
        var walletsHubProxy = $.connection.walletsHub;

        walletsHubProxy.client.updateWallet = function (...) {
            ...
        };

        walletsHubProxy.client.setWallets = function (currentWallets) {
            store.data.wallets = currentWallets;
            store.data.walletsLoaded = true;
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            walletsHubProxy.server.getWallets();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I forgot to mention that the *@Html.HiddenFor* with three parameters is an extension method I wrote to help me with v-bind attributes, which are unparsable by the razor syntax.